# forward class references in Scala?

Tags: scala

I'm running into a standard problem as a newbie to Scala: How do I define two classes in such a way that I can make an instance of one that the other as member variable, which in turn points back to the first instance?

I would like to end up with
  an instance of Game
     which has a member of type Dealer
        which has a member of type Game, which is in fact the original Game instance

So in this case each instance (Game, Dealer) has a member which is the other instance.  Can anyone guide me to the right way to to this?

Answer (score 8):

If you really need to make the classes immutable your only option is to use by name parameters in the constructor and always create instances as lazy `val`s:

```
class Dealer(val name: String, g: => Game) {
  lazy val game = g
  override def toString = "Dealer(name=%s, game=%s)".format(name, game.name)
}

class Game(val name: String, d: => Dealer) {
  lazy val dealer = d
  override def toString = "Game(name=%s, dealer=%s)".format(name, dealer.name)
}

lazy val game: Game = new Game("Doppelkopf", new Dealer("Peter", game))
lazy val dealer: Dealer = new Dealer("Tina", new Game("Poker", dealer))
```

Note that you need the type ascription on the lazy vals or it will not compile.

Comment: @Moriz Whoa! That is some fancy lines of programming. It just goes to show that everything is possible in Scala.

Comment: The above does not compile for me.

Comment: <console>:5: error: not found: type Game
       class Dealer(val name: String, g: => Game) {
                                            ^
<console>:5: error: not found: type Dealer
       class Game(val name: String, d: => Dealer) {
                                          ^

Comment: @Tim I assume you're trying to compile this in the REPL.  You'll need to nest all of this code in an object (e.g. `object O { [paste-code-here] }`) so that the compiler has access to the Game class when compiling the Dealer class.  This technique is also useful if you need to define companions in the REPL.  No wrapper object is needed if you drop this code into a source file, of course.

Answer (score 3):

You have two choices here:

1. Make your objects mutable, then just use exactly the same techniques as you would in Java.
2. Make them immutable, then give up the two-way dependencies.

To see why, consider the following transformation between (immutable) trees.
These are both defined with each parent node holding a list of child nodes, but *children don't know their parent*:

```
a               (a)
  b               (b)
    c                c
    d     -->       (d) 
  e                e
    f                f
    g                g
```

Specifically, the node `d` was cloned with the new value.  To do this, we also had to clone all the parent nodes (shown in brackets).

If nodes held their parent, then `c` would have to be "updated" to reflect the new `b` node, and `e, f, g` would have to be updated to reflect the new `a` node.  i.e. *the entire tree* would have to be copied!

By only holding relationships in one direction, from parent to child, it becomes possible to reuse `c, e, f, g` across successive versions of the structure.  This is a powerful optimisation, and is key to writing efficient functional algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are talking about a "two way" dependency, and this is easy to do if max one of the entities are immutable (If you want both to be immutable you should see Moviz solution).

In my example I let the `Game` be the immutable entity. A dealer might not be involved in a game.

```
class Dealer(val name: String){
  var game: Option[Game] = None
}

case class Game(name: String, dealer: Dealer)

// Instanciate the game and the dealer
val olle = new Dealer("Olle")
val ollesGame = Game("Olles Game", olle)
olle.game = Some(ollesGame)
```